# how to create inline button for share message telegram bot php

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I have a message to which I want to add an inline button. When clicking this button the user can forward this message to groups. How can I do this?

```
$keyboard = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
    [['text' => 'forward me to groups']],
]];
HTTPRequest("sendMessage", [
    "chat_id" => $request["message"]["chat"]["id"],
    "text" => "this is a message",
    "reply_markup" => json_encode($keyboard)
]);
```

Comment: Can you try to explain more clearly what this button would do?

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution that i can think of. Aaccording to [Telegram API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), you can pass an optional parameter called `switch_inline_query`. This is not the application of `switch_inline_query` but it can do what you want. Your code will be like this:

```
$keyboard = [
'inline_keyboard' => [
[['text' => 'forward me to groups'], 'switch_inline_query' => 'this is a message'],
]];
HTTPRequest("sendMessage", [
    "chat_id" => $request["message"]["chat"]["id"],
    "text" => "this is a message",
    "reply_markup" => json_encode($keyboard)
]);
```

Pressing the inline button will prompt the user to select one of their groups or chats, open that chat and insert the bot‘s username and the specified message:
`@Yourbot This is a message`

and by pressing send button message will be sent.